# Vertical text with drawtext filter

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any way to overlay vertical (eg, Japanese) text using the `ffmpeg` drawtext filter?

I've searched around but didn't find anything.  [The documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#drawtext-1) makes reference to the `ft_load_flags= vertical_layout` as a parameter to `libfreetype` but searching further came up with nothing.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drawtext using textfile

```
echo "こ
れ
は
蹤
型
で
す
。" > test.txt

ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vf "
drawtext=textfile=test.txt:
fontcolor=white:
font='Noto Serif CJK JP':
fontsize=h/12:
x=w-text_w-20:
y=(h-text_h)/2
" -c:a copy -t 5 output.mp4 -y
ffplay output.mp4
```

Comment: That is a clever solution!  I'll give it a try. Thank you

Comment: Works great. Thank you!